# How to Create a Multiplication Table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a multiplication table. I have tried different ways to do the multiplication but it doesn't work for out in the end. Can you help?

Working code

I want to do the Table in this way:

```js
document.write("<table border='1px'>");
var i, j;
for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
  document.write("Table" + " " + i + "<br>");
  for (j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
    document.write(i + "*" + j + "=" + i * j + "<br>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

this picture shows what I need in the output

[image: the picture]

table 2 then 3 then 4 etc. ( using a nested loop)

Comment: It is difficult to see what the actual question is?

Comment: @Herohtar it's not what I want, please run the code to understand the difference.

Comment: @all_the_way_out it would help if you explained more precisely what the problem is. Your code seems to be making an accurate list of multiplications. Is the problem simply the way it's presented? If so, try explaining (specifically) what you want in the end.

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes it is the problem, I added a picture that shows what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.write("<table border=\"1px\">");
var i, j;
for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
  document.write("<tr><th colspan=\"5\">Table" + " " + i + "</th></tr>");
  for (j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
    document.write("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>*</td><td>" + j + "</td><td>=</td><td>" + i * j + "</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

Comment: This is the answer, THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: if this helps you, and if you can, vote up... Good Luck